# Python: Match multiple variables in each multiple list

Tags: python

May I know how to match a multiple strings against multiple list? I ran the code but it does not give me 'BEC' as its result, why?

```
a = ["A", "B", "C"]
b = ["AB","BB"]
c = ["ABC","BCD","BEC"]

av, bv, cv = 'B', 'AB', 'BEC'

for _a, _b, _c in zip(a,b,c):
    if _a == av and _b == bv and _c == cv:
        print cv # 'BEC'
```

Comment: Are you checking if the values exist in any list (`set([av,bv,cv])<set(a+b+c)`), or if the values exist in each list (`av in a and bv in b and cv in c`)?


Your code doesn't give BEC because `b` is of length 2 and `a`, `c` are both length 3.

Comment: I'm checking if the values exist in each list. I know there's some better way to solve this but I don't know how.

Comment: Then return the variable cv if values of variables av, bv, cv are found within their respective list.

Comment: The simplest and most straightforward way is `if av in a and bv in b and cv in c: print cv`. I can think of a few other ways including making use of `any` but this is the most straightforward solution.

Comment: Yes, how to construct them with any? I think that is more Pythonic.

Comment: Please add your comment in the answer section so that I can give you reputations as a token.

Comment: Ahh okay I got it  **if any((av in a, bv in b, cv in c)):**

Comment: That would convert to `True` if at least one value is in a list, not if all values are in the list. I think all may actually be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
if a in a and bv in b and cv in c: print cv
```

`all` way using in:

```
all((av in a, bv in b, cv in c))
```

Convoluted `all` way for fun:

```
_lists = [a,b,c]
all(value in _lists[i] for i, value in enumerate([av,bv,cv]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product
a = ["A", "B", "C"]
b = ["AB","BB"]
c = ["ABC","BCD","BEC"]

av, bv, cv = 'B', 'AB', 'BEC'
for _a, _b, _c in product(a,b,c):
    if _a == av and _b == bv and _c == cv:
        print cv # 'BEC'
```

Comment: Nice code, but I think `all((av in a, bv in b, cv in c))` suits my need. :)